# How to change icon when selected

Tags: html, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

A simple question but I do not know if it is possible. Can I change an icon when it is clicked? In the case, my icon is gray, I would like it to go blue when clicked but it's pretty hard to do this in my code, so I want to know if it's possible for me to change to another icon when I click, I would then put the other icon with the blue color. While still learning ionic, then there are many doubts. Thank you to anyone who can help me!

```
 <div no-padding>
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="Menu" class="SwipedTabs-tabs">

  <ion-segment-button (click)="selectTab(0)">
    <ion-icon name="icon-ico_gastronomia_off"></ion-icon>
  </ion-segment-button>
```

Comment: is your icon changed by changing the `name` of the `ion-icon` ?

Comment: Yes. I'm using custom icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to bind the attr name and change it via Angular `[]` - which stand for one way data binding;

html

```
<ion-icon [name]="toShowIcon"></ion-icon>
```

ts

```
toShowIcon = 'icon-ico_gastronomia_off';
```

and than change it on click;

If you want to change the icon only one time and stick with it `icona> iconb` use this code ;

```
selectTab() {
  this.toShowIcon = 'your_new_icon_name';
}
```

If you want on click to toggle the icon. `icona > iconb` and then from `iconb > icona` use this;

```
selectTab() {
  if (this.toShowIcon === 'icon-ico_gastronomia_off') {
    this.toShowIcon = 'your_new_icon_name';
  } else {
    this.toShowIcon = 'icon-ico_gastronomia_off';
  }
}
```

Note: You can do for multiples icons as well. You just need to add the logic.

Comment: Thanks for answering me. But I'm still hopeless. My SelectTab already had a few items. I'll show you the complete code of how it is so you can see if anything is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
selectTab(index) {    
this.SwipedTabsIndicator.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d('+(100*index)+'%,0,0)';
this.SwipedTabsSlider.slideTo(index, 500);
// *** changes made only onces;
this.toShowIcon = 'icon-ico_estadia_off';

// *** toggle change
if (this.toShowIcon === 'icon-ico_gastronomia_off') {
    this.toShowIcon = 'icon-ico_estadia_off';
} else {
    this.toShowIcon = 'icon-ico_gastronomia_off';
}

}
```

HTML`<ion-icon [name]="toShowIcon"></ion-icon>`

ts

```
@ViewChild('SwipedTabsSlider') SwipedTabsSlider: Slides;

SwipedTabsIndicator: any = null;
tabs: any = [];
toShowIcon = 'icon-ico_gastronomia_off';

enter code here
```

Comment: Remove the  `// *** changes made only onces; this.toShowIcon = 'icon-ico_estadia_off';` and try again. you added both versions. pick only one.

Comment: I finally got it! Thank you so much for this! Thank you so much :)